# Star sizing is behaving like Auto?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm pretty confused by the behaviour of the WPF Grid control.

Here is the simplest reproduction I could get:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" MinHeight="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Height="200" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you run it, and shrink the window, you will notice that the bottom button gets clipped before the top button begins to shrink.

You can get the desired behaviour by removing `Height="200"` from the button. However, in my actual use case, the button is replaced by a Border containing a ScrollViewer. Although I don't explicitly set a height on either (but I do one the content of the ScrollViewer), the same clipping behaviour is seen.

So, the question:

How can I get the row to ignore the height of its content? Or is there another way to get the same effect?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the question. Your first Button has a fixed size, unless the parent tells him otherwise he WILL use that Height no matter what. Even if the Parent tells him to use only 100 it will just clip it, setting a fixed size means the control has a fixed size. The Star in the RowDefinition does exactly nothing in this case. If you remove the Height in your first button, you will reach a point where the first row hits its MinHeight, and WPF has no other choice but to move the second row out of view.

Comment: +1 for providing a small, reproducible sample of the problem code :)

Comment: @dowhilefor: I understand that the second row will eventually be clipped. I plan to add a minimum height to the window to prevent this. The problem is that the height of the button seems to be holding the row larger than it otherwise would be.

Comment: @KendallFrey I don't think so, your button is 200 in Height, and your Row allows a maximum height of 300. Enable ShowGridLines on your Grid, to see the actual cells of the grid, maybe that gives you a better idea how the grid is resizing. I tried your code in Xamlpad. If the window height is large, the lower row content is filled, the upper row content is exactly 200 and centered in the first row. If i shrink the window, the first row gets smaller until it hits the height of its content, and then the second row begins to shrink,and finally it will be moved out of the window

Comment: @dowhilefor: I think that describes the behaviour pretty well. What I want is to keep the second button from becoming clipped until the first row has reached its minimum height.

Comment: @KendallFrey well, remove the Height on the first button. Then the grid will try to keep the seconds row "desired size" as long as possible, and because the first row nor its content doesn't have a preset fixed size, it will be shrinked as much as possible, until the first rows minheight is reached, If you remove all MinHeights it should already be pretty close to what you want. Otherwhise i already observe what you want. The second row is clipped when the first row mets its size. Not the MinHeight, because the preset size on the Button weights heavier, but besides that its already there.

Comment: @dowhilefor: That's the problem. The 'preset size on the Button weights heavier.'

Comment: @KendallFrey Where exactly is the problem, setting the VerticalAlignment="Stretch" and removing the Height on the button? Giving something a fixed size always weights the heaviest in WPF. If two of these collides, then its a matter of order. But you have to define these limitations and rulesets for a Layout system like WPF does.

Comment: @dowhilefor: I can't remove the height, as I have a control in a ScrollViewer, and the inner control must remain large enough, displaying scroll bars when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your minimum Grid size is 300 (200 for Row1 and 100 for Row2), so the smallest your `Grid` will ever be is 300. If you shrink the Window below that size, it is simply clipping the `Grid` and hiding parts of it, and not scaling it.

Perhaps you can switch to using a `DockPanel` instead?

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MinHeight="100" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Height="200" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="300"  />
</DockPanel>
```

This way your bottom bit will always be docked to the bottom of your screen, while the other content takes up the remaining space.

If you really want to maintain your size ratio, I'd suggest a converter that sets the Height of your content controls to a percentage of the window size.

```
<DockPanel x:Name="Parent">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MinHeight="100" 
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                             ElementName=Parent, 
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentConverter}, 
                             ConverterParameter=0.1}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Height="200" MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="300"  />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I don't understand the part about the minimum size being 300. 100 + 100 = 200. Also, If I resize the window small enough, the top row does shrink, up until the minimum size.

Comment: @KendallFrey No the Height on the button is more important than the Minheight of the row, in fact its just a MinHeight. But your button WANTS to be 200 in Height, so the row, given a MaxHeight of 300, just allows the button. So this gives you 200(Fixed Button height) + 100 (second row min height) = 300.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Why then doesn't the row always stay >= 200? If the window becomes small enough, the row shrinks below the button size.

Comment: @KendallFrey Your `Button` size is making the first row be a minimum of size of `200`. Grids stretch their rows to fit their content size, and won't clip the contents to fit the row size.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand the reason WHY it doesn't work. But I still don't have a solution. I tried the DockPanel, but it didn't expand the bottom row as necessary.

Comment: @KendallFrey i don't observer this, Have a look at these 2 Screenshots: http://img820.imageshack.us/slideshow/webplayer.php?id=screenshot1htn.png. The Button will always keep its size of 200.

Comment: @dowhilefor: The *button* keeps its size. The *row* doesn't.

Comment: @KendallFrey So to give you a solution, use Rachels approach with the dockpanel, in fact copy her first code sample. And remove the Height on the (now second) button. Instead use MinHeight="20" MaxHeight="200"

Comment: @dowhilefor: How many times do I need to tell you? *I can't remove the Height.* Also, the DockPanel does not expand the bottom row as required.

Comment: @KendallFrey Just once, but you want the size to dynamically change, which it can't because you don't want to remove its fixed height. So i just try to give you an alternative. You don't want to remove the Height, then you have to deal with the fact that you don't get any kind of resizing. The last option would be to calculate the Height by hand, like Rachel explained in her last code sample. Or you just set the Height to 200 on the first grid row aswell instead of star, that way the second row will always stay 200 and the second row will adjust. Otherwise i'm out of options.

Comment: @KendallFrey To make the controls in the `DockPanel` stretch based on the parent size, you'll need to use a `Converter`. I have an example in my answer, and just edited it a tiny bit so you'll pass the `ActualHeight` to the Converter, and not the `DockPanel` itself, which means the converter will re-run whenever `ActualHeight` changes.

Comment: @dowhilefor: I do want the ScrollViewer to resize, but its the content that I am setting the size on, and should not resize (the reason for the ScrollViewer). So, it looks like I need to manually calculate the height. :( I had tried a Converter earlier, but had no luck.

Comment: @KendallFrey You should be able to set the `ScrollViewer.VeriticalAlignment="Stretch"` and `ScrollViewer.MinHeight="100"` to make the ScrollViewer stretch and fill all available space without going below a height of 100, then you should be able to set a height on the objects inside the `ScrolViewer` to whatever you want without impacting anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't work. The default alignment is stretch, so that didn't change much.